# Should I stick with Azure or move to AWS?

Tags: cloud

I am a newbie when it comes to cloud computing and currently in my spare time I am using Azure (single virtual machine) to host my angularjs/nodejs/mongodb app. There is no sharding or replication involved and my app is just a simple app with only a few users using.

I am now thinking about investing more time in 2017 in learning about cloud computing and I am not sure whether I should continue with Azure and learn more or jump to AWS.  A friend of mine uses AWS and what surprised me was how well the documentation was written and the learning curve seemed simpler compared to Azure.

However, as I said I will doing all the learning in my spare time and I hope to get certified as well in either.

I am willing to put in lots of hours to learn but I do not want to make a wrong decision.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but... there's no way to answer your question.  Choose whichever is going to work best for you, your business, your needs, whatever. Same thing with certification: You'll get nothing but opinions here. Off-topic (opinion-soliciting, and tool recommendation).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an opinion kind of question, so I will avoid stating that I prefer Azure over AWS (oops, there I said it...).

That said, if you are looking to land a job, AWS may be preferred as many job postings at this time ask for AWS experience. I expect this will change as Azure becomes more mainstream.

As far as being a newbie, I don't know about the documentation but having tried both AWS and Azure, Azure to me has a much easier to use UI. Anyone can create a web app in just a couple of clicks, so perhaps it might be the easier place to start.

EDIT: why not create a simple web app and try hosting it on both to see which you prefer?

Comment: No. Just no. Don't answer these types of questions. This is just silly. Azure *is* mainstream. Plenty of docs on both cloud platforms. Not the place to pitch your opinion on one cloud provider over another.

Comment: Not trying to start a war, just trying to give a little direction as I wasn't sure of his reason for trying to decide. Your comment also contains opinion. ;)